# no sirve el siguiente codigo

Tags: java

Tengo una exposicion sobre programacion multicore y encontre este ejemplo en un libro, quiero saber que hace y el porque no funciona.

## Codigo para java

```
public class Sum
{
    private int sum;
    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
    public void setSum(int sum) {
        this.sum = sum;
    }
}
class Summation implements Runnable
{
    private int upper;
    private Sum sumValue;
    public Summation(int upper, Sum sumValue) {
        this.upper = upper;
        this.sumValue = sumValue;
    }
    public void run() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= upper; i++)
            sum += i;
        sumValue.setSum(sum);
    }
}
```

Esta parte del codigo es la que creo que se debe ejecutar pero por alguna razon que desconozco me manda al mensaje de error

```
public class sdv
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(args[0]) < 0)
                System.err.println(args[0] + " must be >= 0.");
            else {
                Sum sumObject = new Sum();
                int upper = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                Thread thrd = new Thread(new Summation(upper, sumObject));
                thrd.start();
                try {
                    thrd.join();
                    System.out.println
                    ("The sum of "+upper+" is "+sumObject.getSum());
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) { }
            }
        }
        else
            System.err.println("Usage: Summation <integer value>"); }
}
```

Comment: Nosotros tampoco lo sabríamos a primera vista, por favor considera editar y agregar por ejemplo al ejecutarlo que resultado esperas y cual obtienes de modo que la ayuda que la comunidad te pueda brindar sea mas certera al conocer todos los detalles

Comment: ese es el problema, como escribi inicialmente este codigo lo encontre de ejemplo en un libro pero no dice para que es, por lo que no se que debe ejecutar pero si lo ejecuto asi inicialmente pues resulta en el mensaje de error

Answer (score 1):

Al ejecutar el programa salta al mensaje de error por la validación que tienes al principio:

```
if (args.length > 0) {
```

Si ejecutas el programa sin pasar parámetros de entrada, comprueba que la longitud del array `args` esta vacío (o sea menor que 0) por eso salta al `else`.

Puedes utilizar el símbolo de sistema (`cmd`) en el caso de windows o la terminal en caso de Linux o Mac.

Utilizar el comando `javac` para compilar el archivo `sdv.java`

```
javac sdv.java
```

Esto hará que se genere dos archivos `.class`: **sdv.class** y **Sum.class**

Lo siguiente seria utilizar el comando `java` para ejecutar el archivo **sdv.class** el cual contiene la clase `main`.

```
java sdv.class 4
```

Nos saldrá en la terminal: *The sum of 4 is 10*

**¿Porque?**

Esa es la finalidad del programa. Le pasas un número como parámetro y realiza la suma de todos los números desde el 0 hasta `n`, siendo `n` el número utilizado como parámetro.

**Input**

```
4
```

**Output**

```
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
The sum of 4 is 10
```

Espero que sea de utilidad.

Te dejo un enlace con información sobre el parámetro `args` de la clase `main` [Enlace](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2012/08/el-argumento-args-de-main-en-java.html)